# subclipse alternative

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SVN plugins for Eclipse - Subclipse vs. Subversive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive)

I've been using Subclipse (an SVN plugin for Eclipse), for quite a while, but have become increasingly unhappy with it. I notice that Tortoise SVN is available as an Eclipse plugin and am considering using that instead within Eclipse (I already use it when accessing SVN outside Eclipse).

Before I make the switch, does anyone have any experience with using the Tortoise SVN Eclipse plugin, or are there any other Eclipse SVN plugins (other than Subclipse) that are recommended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**SVN plugins for Eclipse - Subclipse vs. Subversive**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive#61328)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Subversive plugin for Eclipse ?
http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/

Maybe you can explain why you are unhappy with Subclipse, to see if others tools can satisfy you...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with the Totoise SVN plugin, because all my machines run Linux, and last time I checked the tortoise SVN plugin was Windows only.

Another good SVN plugin howver, is Subversive: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

I use tortiseSVN and have had nothing but a positive experience.

Comment: But do you use the Tortoise SVN Eclipse plugin, or you only use it outside Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If you use tortoiseSVN and consider using an Eclipse plugin, stick to Subclipse.

Subversive will simply destroy its cache as soon as you access the SVN server with a different tool (including the command line) just once.