# Files missing in Subclipse Synchronize view

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I recently switched from Subversion to Subclipse¹. I really like the Snychronize view, since it allows me to see everything that's changed and commit with a single click. However, I've noticed that some of the changed files are missing. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Note that the Synchronize view in the lower right-hand corner only shows the changed files in the `src` subfolder, whereas the there are a lot more modified files available (e.g. `AndroidManifest.xml`, `lint.xml` and a bunch of files below `res`). Is this by design (if yes, how can I change it?) or did I stumble upon a bug?

PS: Calling `Commit` in the Snychronize view only commits those few files in src, while selecting `Team/Commit` from the context menu of the project commits *all* changed files. Restarting Eclipse or resyncing in the synchronize view does not fix the problem.

---

¹ ...because [moving files does not work well in Subversive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420013/conveniently-move-a-class-to-a-different-package-in-eclipse-without-borking-svn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your synchronize view only shows the folder ../tablet. Do a Team -> Synchronize with repository on the project root.

Comment: Argh... how could I miss that, it was written plainly in the header of the Synchronize view. I feel a bit stupid now. Anyway, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I would add that there is a button on the Synchronize view to start a Synch and you can choose an option to do all SVN projects in the workspace.  You can then "pin" that Synchronization and set it to refresh automatically on a schedule, like every hour.  Then you never really need to run the Sync action and the view is always showing info.