# SVN client integration into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I had integrated a Subclipse plugin into the Eclipse to perform SVN related operations.

I had successfully checked-in, checked-out and commited my project to the SVN.

But now when I am trying to commit or update my project, it is showing the following error

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Unsupported working copy format

svn: This client is too old to work with working copy 'D:\EclipseWorkspace\EMSEclipse'; please get a newer Subversion client
```

I had tried to update the plugin through **HELP >> SOFTWARE UPDATES...** of the Eclipse but it is saying that the software is up to date and no newer version is available.

Should I switch to some other SVN Client. If yes, then could you please suggest me any other SVN Client for Eclipse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subclipse has different update sites for the 1.4 and 1.6 branches. So if you are using 1.4, it won't have updates. [Get the 1.6 update site](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess).

Whenever the subclipse plugin is not sufficient for you, you can download [Turtoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) - it is a full-featured SVN client.

Comment: I am using Eclipse 3.4.2 and Subclipse 1.0.7. Is this combination creating problem? ........... I had been using Tortoise SVN external to Eclipse. But now I want something that can work within Eclipse. I think Tortoise SVN doesn't work with Eclipse. Rigth?

Comment: subclipse 1.0.7 is waay old. Move to 1.6.x. Turtoise SVN is not working with eclipse, but is useful sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

[Subversive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive) is the other Eclipse client for SVN

But for your error, the solution is indeed to upgrade. Did you check the [Download and installation process](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA)?

As documented, get the [right version of JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL).

Comment: @Yatendra: for eclipse3.4.x, you should have at least Subclipse1.4.x or more recent. Subclipse1.0.x was for Eclipse3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't personally seen that error before. The other popular SVN client for Eclipse is [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) in-case you want to try that.