# Why isn't SVN Checkout an option for me when I'm creating a new project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ubuntu

I recently just installed Eclipse onto a Ubuntu 10.04 machine.

Now, I'm reading "Getting Started" instructions for a project I want to contribute with and they state the following:

```
Using Eclipse Galileo for Java part:

File -> New -> Other  
SVN -> Checkout projects from SVN  
Create a new repository location http://marioai.googlecode.com/svn/trunk or use the existing one  
Next >  
Select "Check out as a project configured using the New Project Wizard"  
Next > (You will see a project creation wizard)  
Select "Java Project"  
Name the project, say "MarioAI" and select a location  
Make root folder as source folder  
Configure inclusion and exclusion filters  
Press Add and put down '.lvl', '.dat'  
Finish
```

However, SVN -> Checkout isn't an option for me.

I've apt-get installed both Eclipse and Subversion.  Do I have to do something else to my install in order to get this new project type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install an Eclipse plugin for Subversion. That is either [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA) or [subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/). You can easily install one of these in Eclipse with Help->Install new software. Some instructions on how to install plugins are [here](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/install_plugin/index_v35.html)

Comment: Would you suggest one over the other?

Comment: see this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive
I use subclipse for historical reasons.