# How to use "svn export" command to get a single file from the repository?

Tags: windows, svn

How can I use the `svn export` command to get a single file from the repository?

I've tried this:

```
svn export e:\repositories\process\test.txt c:\
```

But I get this error:

> svn: e:\repositories\process is not a working copy

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Guessing from your directory name, you are trying to access the repository on the local filesystem. You still need to use URL syntax to access it:

```
svn export file:///e:/repositories/process/test.txt c:\test.txt
```

Comment: I think you don't even need to provide complete path using file:// scheme; Just move to the directory where you code resides and use svn export command there.

For example you code is present in someting/someting/code, so mov to something/something us cd command and run the following command

svn export ./code ./code_new

this command will export all your code in code_new directory. Note that you don't even need to cread code_new directory yourself, export command will do it itself.

correct me if I'm wrong at any place.

Answer (score 20):

You don't have to do this locally either.  You can do it through a remote repository, for example:

```
svn export http://<repo>/process/test.txt /path/to/code/
```

Comment: "Not found."  Is there another link that I could try, @RobertDuchnik ?

Comment: You didn't seriously try a URL with `<repo>` in there literally, did you? That was just meant as an example, you need to fill in your actual repository path from the server.

Comment: Withdrawn by Comment Poster

Answer (score 5):

For the substition impaired here is a real example from GitHub.com to a local directory:

```
svn ls https://github.com/rdcarp/playing-cards/trunk/PumpkinSoup.PlayingCards.Interfaces
svn export https://github.com/rdcarp/playing-cards/trunk/PumpkinSoup.PlayingCards.Interfaces /temp/SvnExport/Washburn
```

See: [Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use SVN repository URL to export file to Local path.

```
     svn export [-r rev] [--ignore-externals] URL Export_PATH
     svn export http://<path>/test.txt C:\Temp-Folder
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP was asking about doing the export from the command line, but just in case this is helpful to anyone else out there...

You could just let **Eclipse** (plus one of the [plugins discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-and-subvers)) do the work for you.

Obviously, downloading [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) just for doing a single export is overkill, but if you are already using it for development, you can also do an `svn export` simply from your IDE's context menu when browsing an SVN repository.

**Advantages**:

- easier for those not so familiar with using SVN at the command-line level (but you can learn about what happens at the command-line level by looking at the SVN console with a range of commands)
- you'd already have your SVN details set up and wouldn't have to worry about authenticating, etc.
- you don't have to worry about mistyping the URL, or remembering the order of parameters
- you can specify in a dialog which directory you'd like to export to
- you can specify in a dialog whether you'd like to export from TRUNK/HEAD or use a specific revision