# java library version numbering using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-numbering

I'm developing a library connected SVN @sourceforge, My IDE is Eclipse, so how to setup version numbering ? I guess it's automatic but how do I do that using Eclipse ?

---

NOTE: I'm using Subclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using Java and this is a new application.  In that case I recommend setting up your project with Maven and using the Release plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) or the Versions plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).  Here is a link on how to get started with the Versions plugin once you have Maven set up:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/08/18/managing-version-numbers-maven-maven-versions-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Subversion numbers the commits starting from one, nothing you could change about that. As plugin for svn you could use [Subclipse or Subversive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive) For the version numbers of your application you have to decide by yourself how to number it, and create a copy of the code in the svn repository, usually in the tag folder (while the main development would be in the tunk), a directory with the version number. You could do it with the features of whatever SVN plugin for eclipse you choose.

Comment: I forgot to say that i'm using Subclipse sorry, so how do number the version using it ?

Comment: @Ismail do you want to create a new Tag, or just the number of the svn commit?

Comment: I want to do it Major.minor.qualifier version number for the project and I want to know how to do that automatically ? and what is best way to do it ?

Comment: Then I think it's best to go with the answer of Matthew Ratzloff. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994433/java-library-version-numbering-using-eclipse/5994947#5994947

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague.  When you say "version numbering", I assume you mean Subversion revision numbering and not application version numbering (e.g., 1.0.0).  And I'm also assuming that you're asking how to put revision numbers in comments of the file itself.

In the header of your files, you'll want to add the following:

```
$LastChangedDate:$
$LastChangedRevision:$
$LastChangedBy:$
```

Next in ~/subversion/config add the following:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
* = svn:keywords=LastChangedDate LastChangedRevision LastChangedBy Id
```

Finally in Eclipse go to Windows > Preferences > Team > SVN and set "Configuration location" to "Use directory" and select ~/subversion.

Source: http://islandlinux.org/howto/enable-auto-properties-auto-props-subversion-subclipse-eclipse

Comment: I'm sorry for being vage i'm a newbie, no I meant actually the other thing "Application version numbering 1.0.0"