# Does Erlide ( Erlang IDE on Eclipse ) work well with source control systems ( Git or SVN )?

Tags: erlang, erlide

I've been working on several projects involving Erlang in Eclipse ( using the Erlide plugin ) and dealing with erlang is somehow problematic in such IDE since it is hard to visualize the set of changes across all erlang source files that were modified.

When I use Netbeans for Java purposes, integrated to a centralized SVN, I can see all add/update/delete changes in different collors, compared to the last time I have committed such changes in source control system.

I tried to achieve the same with Eclipse + Erlide, but it does not appear possible. Somehow it is hard to understand the visual benefits of that.

Did anyone succeed well using a version control with Erlide, for the above purposes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Netbeans, so I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The VCS plugins are providing the functionality related to version handling, the only thing that is specific for different languages is the support for structured comparison of versions.

I would suggest you try Eclipse+Java and if they do what you want and we don't, then file a ticket for that at https://erlide-tools.assembla.com/spaces/erlide/support/tickets

Comment: you are correct. I could not identify issues after using SVN locally with Eclipse/Erlide. The setup is somehow complicated ( for the highlighting of changes ), but that complexity comes from Eclipse itself rather than the Erlide plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Subclipse  plugin works well for me. There are mainly two plugins for SVN, [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) and [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/). Check the SVN [plugin comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive) link for more information.