# Groovy Grails Tool Suite with Subversion

Tags: eclipse, svn, grails

I see two options for using Groovy Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) with Subversion.

A) Use the GGTS Subversion plugin....http://grails.org/plugin/svn

B) Use the Eclipse Subversive plugin......http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/

I'm on a Windows 7 box and I have an existing Groovy Grails project that I need to load into a newly created and currently empty subversion repository on my CentOS 6x linux server. I've set up svn+ssh with putty/pageant and that's working.

Would option A or B work better and how would do I go about getting an existing Grails project into the subversion repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option A is a Grails plugin. This is helpful if you want to add support for Subversion in your own application.

Option B is an Eclipse plugin. This adds Subversion as a team provider in your Eclipse development environment. This is what you want.

There is also [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) if you want an alternative to Option B.

Comment: Thanks, Henrik. Are your A and B in sync with my Q?  After reading the description for each, it appears that you got them switched?  And, I am looking for a Team Providor, so that inside GGTS/Eclipse, I can do similar operations that I'd get out of Tortoise as I work with my projects.  So, Subclipse appears to be another viable option.

Comment: Here's a comparison of Subversion and Subclipse: [link on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive)

Comment: @Twelve24: I corrected this. It was only a typo in the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to Go to Help -> Market place then search for svn and then Add