# GGTS Grails SVN Subversion

Tags: svn, spring-tool-suite

i'm developing a webapp in grails GGTS(version 3.4.0) and now i need to share the project with Subversion (SVN).

I tried to install svn plugin but this isn't work.

THen i tried to install Subversive extension from Extension tab of GGTS. Svn was installed fine, but, when i try to share the project on a repository online, i get error of MKACTIVITY (for google code repository) and for riouxsvn (riouxsvn.com) i can't log in with my credentials.

Anyone have problem with svn on ggts 3.4.0???
Any solution for this?

## EDIT:

I have installed Subversive again and I tried to import svn project form repository, but the project is imported without file... and when i try to right click on project and go to Team, the menu is empty...

Answer (score 1):

http://grails.org/Checking+Projects+into+SVN

[Groovy Grails Tool Suite with Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434007/groovy-grails-tool-suite-with-subversion)

I am sure that there are many ways to do this.  I will describe my process and let you glean from it what you will:

1. In the Help menu, choose the "Install New Software..." option.
2. Subversion can be installed from the url "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno".  This is set at a drop-down at the top of the dialog titled "Work with:".
3. In the list of software below the "Work with:" drop-down, expand Collaboration and choose a product (like "Subversive SVN Team Provider").  Choose an SVN connector (for me, this was SVNKit 1.7.8).  This should require the credentials for your repository.
4. Move the required code to the repository.  I use Tortoise SVN and the repo-browser to move my code to project folder with "branch", "tags", and "trunk" subfolders.  The "trunk" holds the source code.