# SVN Repository Exploring Perspective for Eclipse missing

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I just installed the latest version of Eclipse Mars IDE for Java Developers using the Installer for my 64-bit Windows 10 and I was trying to connect my workspace to a SVN repository but I couldn't find the SVN Repository Exploring Perspective at all. I went from "Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other..." and I couldn't find it there at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was also shocked that they removed SVN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal, the SVN perspective is only present when there is a SVN plugin installed for Eclipse. By default, no such plugin is installed.

The two main plugins are [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) and [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/). You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61320/1743880) for a comparison of the two.

Comment: really? Last time I used the Installer the work space that I created already had the SVN good to go. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @sd You can check [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars1) all the features installed by default (Git is there but not SVN). I don't know why it worked for you last time however.