# svn connector and plug in

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse, subversive

I am new to svn. Currently, I am looking for svn which is suitable for me to implement in my company. I had use 2 days to research, as a result, I know that subversive, subclipse, and tortoise svn are famous svn.
The follows are my question :

1. 3 of these svn need svn connector to interconnect right? or the connector already bundle together with the svn?
2. There are only 2 types of svn connector which are svnkit and javahl, am I correct?
3. Except these 3 svn (subclipse, subversive, tortoise), is there still any other svn can recommend for me?
4. Tortoise svn are different with (subversive and subclipse) right? since tortoise svn can be file based and also able to connect it through the eclipse plug in? Where as subversive and subclipse just a part(plug in) of eclipse?
5. Can I use tortoise svn and subclipse interconnect?

   6. So far, only subversive and subclipse are plugin which can integrate with eclipse? where as VisualSVN,assembla, riouxsvn and so on are software right? can we can we host the svn server like visualsvn ourself? or we have to buy the service from the official website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows, I would recommend using Tortoise SVN.

- 32 Bit: [32 Bit installer 1.9.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.9.3/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.9.3.27038-win32-svn-1.9.3.msi/download?accel_key=61%3A1457943637%3Ahttps%253A//tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html%3A6c666b36%249971081930b067fddfb03431e7c7c4a0570449c9&click_id=a199a00e-e9bd-11e5-83fa-0200ac1d1d8e&source=accel)
- 64 Bit: [64 Bit installer 1.9.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.9.3/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.9.3.27038-x64-svn-1.9.3.msi/download?accel_key=61%3A1457943637%3Ahttps%253A//tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html%3A6c666b36%249971081930b067fddfb03431e7c7c4a0570449c9&click_id=a199a00e-e9bd-11e5-83fa-0200ac1d1d8e-1&source=accel)

The main features are:

- all commands are available directly from the Windows Explorer.
- only commands that make sense for the selected file/folder are shown. You won't see any commands that you can't use in your situation.
- See the status of your files directly in the Windows explorer
- allows moving files by right-dragging them in the Windows explorer

If you need also a svn server you could also use tortoise svn, but if you have a linux machine, I would recommend using the apache version.

Subversive is the "eclipse svn provider". I think it is more widely used then subclipse. For more info: [pros-and-cons-of-the-svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-and-subvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-and-subvers)

Comment: hi thanks for your prompt reply. may i know can tortoise svn apache and window version can sync up? the main advantages of tortoise svn is they provide GUI right?